# Using a list inside the Dictionary type

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures

I am trying to further a specific question that was asked and answered here.
[Method chaining generic list extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481175/method-chaining-generic-list-extensions/481208#481208)

My question now is, how would I access the lists INSIDE that dictionary data type so that it would display both bits of text?

Comment: You need to bulk up this question a bit. You can't expect your responders to do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> dict; // given

foreach(var kvp in dict)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}",
    kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Aggregate((c,n)=>c+=','+n)));
}
```